# TableFactory PDFTable outputs only column headers

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to create a table using `TableFactory` but there is almost no documentation and only [two](https://github.com/kstrauser/tablefactory) [examples](http://kstrauser.github.io/tablefactory/) that I can find. The `PDFTable` function does output a PDF but it doesn't seem to be finding the data!

My code:

```
#Import module components
from TableFactory import *

# Build the data setup required
ids = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

lon = [-80.15765381, -80.40131378, -80.56086731, -80.52893066,
       -80.24595642, -80.7718277, -80.877388, -79.9454422, -79.84288025]

lat = [ 0.34739658, -0.39966396, -0.91119879,  0.83061123,  0.67057306,
       -0.1843673, -0.18189907,  0.43762371,  0.45526683]

depth = [ 14044, 4942, 7000, 13107,
         6281, 7000, 1172, 4825, 6730]

rows4 = TableRow()
setattr(rows4, 'ids', ids)
setattr(rows4, 'lon', lon)
setattr(rows4, 'lat', lat)
setattr(rows4, 'depth', depth)


invoicerow = RowSpec(ColumnSpec('ids', 'Event ID'),
                     ColumnSpec('lon', 'Longitude'),
                     ColumnSpec('lat', 'Latitude'),
                     ColumnSpec('depth', 'Depth'))

lines = invoicerow.makeall(rows4)

#create the tables
#HTML
HTMLTable('Invoices by Customer',
          'Amount of each invoice, sorted by invoiceid',
          headers=invoicerow).render(lines)

# Excel
SpreadsheetTable('Invoices by Customer',
                 'Amount of each invoice, sorted by invoiceid',
                 headers=invoicerow).render(lines)

# PDF
pdfmaker = PDFTable('My title',
                    headers=invoicerow)

open('invoicetable.pdf', 'wb').write(pdfmaker.render(lines))
```

But it doesn't produce what I would have expected:

[image]

Comment: as a note: I made a pretty big edit as I solved the initial thing I thought was the issue but turns out there was a different underlying one. Editted to shift the questions focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close! Here's how I reworked it slightly:

```
#Import module components
from collections import namedtuple

from TableFactory import *

# Build the data setup required
ids = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

lon = [-80.15765381, -80.40131378, -80.56086731, -80.52893066,
       -80.24595642, -80.7718277 , -80.877388  , -79.9454422 , -79.84288025]

lat = [ 0.34739658, -0.39966396, -0.91119879,  0.83061123,  0.67057306,
       -0.1843673 , -0.18189907,  0.43762371,  0.45526683]

depth = [ 14044.31152 ,   4942.527294,   7000.      ,  13107.94449 ,
         6281.775475,   7000.      ,   1172.017574,   4825.51527 ,
         6730.996132]

# Make an object that can represent a row in the table. This could be
# a full-blown class, or a dict like {'id': 'a', 'lon': 0.3, ...}, etc.
DataRow = namedtuple('DataRow', ['id', 'lon', 'lat', 'depth'])

# Combine the separate lists together into a list of DataRow objects
rows = [DataRow(*_) for _ in zip(ids, lon, lat, depth)]

invoicerow = RowSpec(ColumnSpec('id', 'Event ID'),
                     ColumnSpec('lon', 'Longitude'),
                     ColumnSpec('lat', 'Latitude'),
                     ColumnSpec('depth', 'Depth'))

lines = invoicerow.makeall(rows)

#create the tables
#HTML
html = HTMLTable('Invoices by Customer',
                 'Amount of each invoice, sorted by invoiceid',
                 headers=invoicerow).render(lines)

# Excel
excel = SpreadsheetTable('Invoices by Customer',
                         'Amount of each invoice, sorted by invoiceid',
                         headers=invoicerow).render(lines)

# PDF
pdf = PDFTable('Invoices by Customer',
               'Amount of each invoice, sorted by invoiceid',
               headers=invoicerow).render(lines)

with open('my.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(pdf)
```

Basically, TableFactory expects a list of rows objects, not a list of columns. I turned your column lists (`ids`, `lon`, `lat`, `depth`) into a list of DataRow objects that TableFactory could chew on.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question I think while you were writing that but it does still solve the problem and I get a full pdf output now. It does seem to crash the GUI (`Spyder`) each time it renders the PDF though and I'm not sure why!

Comment: It will crash on both the SpreadsheetTable and PDFTable lines, forcing me to restart, but it does still produce the full PDF. This computer is getting a bit old so it could be it freezing up due to RAM requirements or something.